Recording audio with a Discord.py bot
I'm trying to make a Discord bot that forwards sound from one channel to another (with consent from the individuals being recorded).
The problem I've encountered is that when multiple people are talking, the audio rapidly switches between them, which makes the sound choppy and unintelligible.
DISCLAIMER: I've never really worked with audio, so I apologize if this is a silly question with an obvious answer.
import discord
import pyaudio
from discord.ext import commands, voice_recv

class MyAudioSource(discord.PCMAudio):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream

    def read(self):
        return self.stream.read(CHUNK)
    
    def is_opus(self):
        return False
    
class MyAudioSink(voice_recv.AudioSink):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream

    def write(self, user, data):
        self.stream.write(data.pcm)
        
    def wants_opus(self):
        return False
    
    def cleanup(self):
        return

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 48000
CHUNK = (RATE // 1000) * 20

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

loopback_stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT,
                             channels=CHANNELS,
                             rate=RATE,
                             input=True,
                             output=True,
                             input_device_index=2, # VAC's that lead into eachother for playback
                             output_device_index=6, # VAC's that lead into eachother for playback
                             frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

    target_channel = bot.get_channel(1262072403698257973)
    target_client = await target_channel.connect(cls=voice_recv.VoiceRecvClient)
    
    #secret_channel = bot.get_channel(1262069846259142701)
    #secret_client = await secret_channel.connect()

    my_audio_sink = MyAudioSink(loopback_stream)
    target_client.listen(my_audio_sink)

    my_audio_source = MyAudioSource(loopback_stream)
    target_client.play(my_audio_source)

    guild = discord.Object(id=1262072402997678140)
    bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=guild)
    await bot.tree.sync(guild=guild)

bot.run("TOKEN")

EDIT:
This is the repo I'm using:
discord-ext-voice-recv

If i'm not wrong there is an option to listen to just one user, as the sink has a param user: def write(self, user: Optional[User], data: VoiceData) -> None: self.cb(user, data), you might be able to list to the connected users and create a listen sink for each user
